# Why does d + down delete two lines in Vim?

Tags: vim, input

This behavior is consistent across all environments where I have used Vim (Cygwin, Putty, VC, xterm & co). I realize that it has something to do with the way input is read and the representaion of <kbd>↓</kbd>, but I'm not sure exactly why the key combination <kbd>d</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> deletes two lines of text. Care to shed some light on this matter?

Comment: If you had told us what you expect instead, we could better correct your misunderstanding.

Comment: I'd like to stick up for the OP - it's not obvious to me why it's *two* lines... rather than just the single character of D+left and D+right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question a few years later:

Because the combination <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> deletes one line, so the next convenient thing to have is two lines, in either direction. There is no logic to it, it's just convenient. The up-down arrow behavior is not consistent with left-right arrows in combination with d. If it were one might expect <kbd>d</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to delete until the end of line or until the beginning of the next line or some other "logical" thing, but it does not. The combination <kbd>d</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> deletes only one character, but <kbd>d</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> deletes two whole lines. It's not logical or consistent, just convenient.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>D</kbd> and a cursor movement, deletes in that direction.  It's just a standard binding.

<kbd>D</kbd> with <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd> works the same way as the arrow keys.

Comment: Exactly. d + down deletes two lines because that is how vim is supposed to work.

Comment: It's actually inconsistent - D+left and D+right delete one character, whereas D+up and D+down delete _two_ lines.  So no, it's not a stupid question.

Comment: It is even worse: `d`+`}` deletes the remainder of the paragraph starting from cursor but `d` + `j` deletes also what is ahead of the cursor. I don't know of any other motion that does not delete from initial cursor position to cursor position after the movement.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> and <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> deletes the current line, and <kbd>d</kbd> in visual mode deletes the highlighted text.  When you move down a line holding <kbd>d</kbd>, you may be highlighting both lines, which then deletes them due to how VIm handles the <kbd>d</kbd> button press.

Answer (score -2):

That behavior is consistent across systems because it is perfectly normal. What in all hell are you expecting `dj` or `d<down>` to do?

`d` is an "operator pending command": after it is pressed, Vim waits for a motion to apply the command to. Since you give it the `<down>` motion, `d<down>` deletes the current line and the line below.

Comment: I could expect a number of things. None of them are naturally associated with hell.